# On form submit using <span> button redirect to new site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, redirect

I need to submit the below form and redirect the page to another site to display the search result as per the input searchString.

```
<a href="#" class="button search">
    <span class="spanclass"></span>
    <input class="expand" name="searchString" type="text">
    <span id="searchButton" class="search icon-small open-btn"></span>
</a>
```

I am wondering how can I process it either using javascript, jquery or ajax. Please provide your valuable inputs. As I have the submit button as span, I am not sure how I can use it to submit the form. Thanks folks in advance for the valuable information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inline js solution

```
<span id="searchButton" class="search icon-small open-btn" onclick="document.forms['form-name'].submit();"></span>
```

but since you also included jquery tag for your question :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#searchButton').click(function(){
     $("#form-id").submit();
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

attach an onlclick function to the span using jquery, and submit the form inside the function

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#searchButton').click(function(){
$("form").submit()//assuming you have a form tag with an action specified
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var SearchedItem=$(".expand").text();      

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "/MyController/Index",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    // processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ SearchedItem: SearchedItem}),
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't work on stack because of the Same Origin Policy in the iframe

```js
$(function(){
  var searchString = $('.expand'),
      searchButton = $('#searchButton');
  
  searchButton.on('click', function(e){
    window.location.href = searchString.val();
  });
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.search-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 2em;
}

.expand {
  width: 260px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.search {
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  background: teal;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-box">
<input class="expand" name="searchString" type="text" value="http://google.com">
<span id="searchButton" class="search icon-small open-btn"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `onclick` event to the element:

```
<span id="searchButton" class="search icon-small open-btn" onclick="location.href = 'www.yoursite.com';"></span>
```

You can also but this in a JavaScript block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("searchButton").onclick = function () {
        location.href = "www.yoursite.com";
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeking to submit the form while the `span` is within this form, a [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) would actually help with no JS involved, as well as cross-browser support:

```
<label>
  <span id="searchButton" class="search icon-small open-btn"></span>
  <input type="submit" style="display:none"/>
</label>
```

Make sure the presence of submit input field (`input type=submit`) within the label otherwise use the [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for) attribute with the field `id` as long as present.